# BigInteger Performance

Tags: java, performance, loops

```
public static BigInteger find(BigInteger A,BigInteger B) 
{ 
     BigInteger res=BigInteger.ONE;
     for(BigInteger i=A;i.compareTo(B)!=0;i.add(BigInteger.ONE)) 
          res=res.add(i);
     /*for(BigInteger i=1;i.compareTo(B)!=0;i.add(BigInteger.ONE)) 
          res=res.multiply(A);*/ 
     return res; 
}
```

my intention is to add any 2 numbers within the range., let's say 2 to 5(2+3+4+5) or A raise to B.  I have other option to get it done within BigInteger, but can anybody say what's wrong with the above snippet in which

1. Its producing longggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg strange number(instead of original) and
2. Its struggling/juggling so much to increment by 1 as it normally increment outside/without loop?
3. When will it reach just one increment(time or space factor/performance)?

Comment: `BigInteger` is immutable, so `i.add(BigInteger.ONE)` doesn't actually modify the value of `i`.

Answer (score 3):

The sum of all integers in a range can be calculated as the *average value* multiplied by the *number of values*, aka the "count".

If `A` and `B` are both *inclusive*, as indicated by the "2 to 5(2+3+4+5)" text in the question, then we have:

```java
average = (A + B) / 2
count = B - A + 1
sum = count * average
    = (B - A + 1) * ((A + B) / 2)
    = (B - A + 1) * (B + A) / 2   // flipped A + B for the symmetry of it
```

In Java code, using `BigInteger`, that means:

```java
public static BigInteger sumRangeInclusive(BigInteger A, BigInteger B) {
    return B.subtract(A).add(BigInteger.ONE).multiply(B.add(A)).shiftRight(1);
}
```

Comment: please use iterative loop

Comment: @SrinivasaMurthyChintalapati Why on earth would I do that? You asked for a `BigInteger` solution that performs well. Eliminating the loop means that performance is constant, i.e. _O(1)_, regardless of how big the value range is. The fact that you're using `BigInteger` means that the value range can be *humongous*, which means that an iterative loop will run ***forever*** (well, almost), which is certainly not good performance.

Comment: @SrinivasaMurthyChintalapati Which point in the question are you referring to? I mean, point 1 claims the code produces long strange number, which is impossible, since the loop never ends. As such, I didn't pay too much attention to the points, and decided so instead show how to do "2 to 5(2+3+4+5)" in a performant way, instead of trying to help you fix a loop that would *never* be able to perform adequately for any extended `BigInteger` range.

Comment: you missed the iterative loop  point. I demonstratively wrote and mentioned clearly..

Comment: @SrinivasaMurthyChintalapati And it seems that you're missing the point of this answer, because an iterative solution **will not perform**, even if your attempt gets fixed, and the code in this answer will. Yes, you demonstratively showed an iteration approach, but that is the wrong *approach* for summing numbers in a range, so I showed you a better approach. Making perfect code for a lousy algorithm will still result in lousy code. Better to first find a better algorithm, *then* you can work on perfecting the code.

Comment: @SrinivasaMurthyChintalapati I believe you need to work on your clarity before posting questions here or you will struggle to gain any reputation. You say you are being clear but in fact this question is very unclear.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is an issue with storing value of the loop variable after increment.

The sum of arithmetic progression should include both `A` and `B`:

```java
public static BigInteger find(BigInteger A,BigInteger B) 
{ 
     BigInteger sum = BigInteger.ZERO;
     for (BigInteger i = A; i.compareTo(B) <=0; i = i.add(BigInteger.ONE)) {
         sum = sum.add(i);
     }
     return sum; 
}
```

Tests:

```
System.out.println(find(new BigInteger("2"), BigInteger.valueOf(5)));
System.out.println(find(new BigInteger("200"), BigInteger.valueOf(500)));
```

Output:

```
14
105350
```

Comment: thats ok 1)when will 2 become 3? 3 become 4? ... 2)the compareTo gives you 3 results -1 iff A<B,0 A=B,1 A>B and 3) If I enter 2 as a `BigInteger`for A, it should appear as2 not some `1914314` junk value. 4) If some junk value appears as initial  then when will it reach final value?

Comment: 1) `2` becomes `3` and so on with this fix: `i = i.add(BigInteger.ONE)` -- it's increment; 2) `compareTo` will be comparing _changing_ value `i` to the fixed `B` while i <= B; 3) and 4) are non-reproducible issues and you may need to clarify _what you do_ to get junk value of `2`.

Comment: writing loop is important, for given snippet infant can do fixes.

Comment: Excuse me?  Isn't there a loop over there for over 2 hours?

Answer (score 0):

A better way to solve this would be by applying simple arithmetic. We know that:

**Sum of natural numbers up to n** = `n * (n + 1) / 2`

**Sum of natural numbers from m to n** = `Sum of natural numbers up to n` minus `Sum of natural numbers up to m - 1` =  `n * (n + 1) / 2` - `(m - 1) * (m - 1 + 1) / 2` = `n * (n + 1) / 2` - `(m - 1) * (m) / 2` = `(n * (n + 1)  - (m - 1) * m) / 2`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(find(BigInteger.valueOf(123456789), BigInteger.valueOf(987654321)));
    }

    public static BigInteger find(BigInteger A, BigInteger B) {
        return B.multiply(B.add(BigInteger.ONE)).subtract(A.subtract(BigInteger.ONE).multiply(A))
                .divide(BigInteger.TWO);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
480109740075445815
```

### What is wrong with your code?

1. The loop terminates when `A` becomes equal to `B` whereas it should terminate when `A` becomes greater than `B`. For this, you can use the terminating condition as `i.compareTo(B.add(BigInteger.ONE)) != 0`.
2. A [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) is an immutable arbitrary-precision integer. Therefore,  `i.add(BigInteger.ONE)` won't modify the value of `i`. You need to assign the result to `i` i.e. `i = i.add(BigInteger.ONE)` in order to increment the value referenced by `i` by one.
3. You have started with a value `1` (i.e. `BigInteger res=BigInteger.ONE`) instead of `0`.

**Correct code:**

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(find(BigInteger.valueOf(2), BigInteger.valueOf(5)));
    }

    public static BigInteger find(BigInteger A, BigInteger B) {
        BigInteger res = BigInteger.ZERO;
        for (BigInteger i = A; i.compareTo(B.add(BigInteger.ONE)) != 0; i = i.add(BigInteger.ONE))
            res = res.add(i);
        return res;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
14
```

Although you can get the correct result after correcting your code this way, it's performance will be extremely bad.

Comment: `i.compareTo(B.add(BigInteger.ONE)) != 0` is better written as `i.compareTo(B) <= 0`, since it saves an extra `BigInteger` object instance for each iteration of the loop. With that change, the code has already been shown in [answer by Alex Rudenko](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64637353/5221149).

Comment: @Andreas - The answer you have pointed to (i.e. [answer by Alex Rudenko](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64637353/10819573)) won't even compile and you have downvoted my answer preferring that. Interesting! Also, your statement, `since it saves an extra BigInteger object instance for each iteration of the loop.` is not correct. No compiler in the Java world will do so...the optimization will take care of that.

Comment: You truly believe that *all* JVM implementations will evaluate `i.compareTo(B.add(BigInteger.ONE))` without creating a new `BigInteger` instance to pass with the `compareTo()` method? Wow!  --- I had down-voted because the result was incorrect. Sorry I forgot to remove that when you fixed it. Done now.

Comment: @Andreas - Your comment has `...for each iteration of the loop...` which is not correct. Only one instance will be created for `all` iterations of the loop, not for `each` iteration of the loop. I am not sure of a JVM implementation 20 years ago, but no JVM implementation since the last decade would have done it differently.

Comment: @AlexRudenko Fix `return res;` -> `return sum;` then it compiles. Arvind is being pedantic.

Comment: `BigInteger` immutable? if that would be the case then res is a `BigInteger` and we are manipulating it only, that means its keep on changing. So where is immutability came all of sudden?

Comment: @SrinivasaMurthyChintalapati BigInteger's immutability came from [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html): _Immutable arbitrary-precision integers. All operations behave as if BigIntegers were represented in two's-complement notation (like Java's primitive integer types)._  All of a sudden.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash So you believe that *all* JVM implementations will analyze `add()` deep enough to recognize that the method is *deterministic*, so that `B.add(BigInteger.ONE)` can be refactored outside the loop? Sure, if `B` was an `int`, then `B + 1` would, but how deep do you believe the code analysis for detecting whether methods are *deterministic* goes? In *all* JVM implementations?

Comment: @SrinivasaMurthyChintalapati - I've added the documentation link in `point#2`. I hope, you understand the concept of an immutable object. When an operation on an immutable object is supposed to produce a new value, a new object is produced while the existing reference keeps pointing to the original object. Therefore, if you want the existing reference to point to the new object, you need to assign the new object to the existing reference explicitly.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash your `BigInteger.valueOf(2)` has limitation. What if I use some BIGNUMBER i.e. BigInteger.valueOf(?) Ttusssssssssssssssssss Tussssssssssssss Dhummmmmmmm, Early Diwali

Answer (score 0):

my option for A raises to B **without generating multiple instances**

```
public static BigInteger find(BigInteger A,BigInteger B)
    {
        BigInteger res=BigInteger.ONE;
        int b=B.intValue();
        for(int i=1;i<=b;i++)
            res=res.multiply(A);
        return res;
    }
```

Comment: Wow!  While there's a battle over calculation of the sum of arithmetic progression, a self answer is about raising A to power B, with the loop using primitive `int` which not every infant is able to write :)

Comment: :) @AlexRudenko you please try to find fact(N) or n!, s you aware there is no builtin function available.

Comment: @AlexRudenko iterative in nature you know :)

Comment: What for?  There's a fresh question with a working example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64638501/factorial-of-giant-number-not-oveflowing-stack-but-also-not-returning-the-result

Comment: hahaha yes yes! I will produce the final result for factorial of course at end! You don't worry!