# Factorial of giant number not oveflowing stack but also not returning the result (JAVA)

Tags: java, recursion, jvm, biginteger, tail-recursion

**EDIT : I am specifically trying to look at this problem as a tail-recursive function. Using an iterative solution is not an option.**

I am trying to put together a factorial calculator that can handle any integer as input as long as the result is < 2^2147483647 (Since I am using BigInteger to do it).

I am running into an issue where the result of the factorial only prints as output SOMETIMES, even though I do not believe I have passed the capacity of the stack. It seems to work consistently for values under ~8000 (estimated, was not the same each execution..?), but intermittently prints nothing for values between ~8000 and ~31400 (showing blank returns increasingly often as number go up..?).

One execution I got 13947 as the highest integer handled before the stack overflow, another time it was in the 12000s. I'm thinking at least that much can be attributed to variable stack states during execution (since user input is taken and changes each time), but I am a fairly new programmer and my theoretical understanding on some things can be shaky, so I am not sure.

Does anyone know why the code might be printing nothing for some high values? My best guesses are

1. that result is larger than 2^2147483647, so it can't be stored as BigInteger, (but that doesn't explain the intermittent-ness...)
2. The calculation is somehow taking too long and the loop is continuing before calculation is finished (explains intermittent-ness but seems impossible)
3. My Eclipse IDE just doesn't handle printing that many digits to the screen well, even though calculation is happening.

I am not sure how to validate above guesses. I have read about the limitations of BigInteger, as well as Eclipse limitations but have not found any answer that I can compare to my task.

Here is the code :

```
package factorielRecursiveTerminale;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class factorielRecursiveTerminale {  
static BigInteger factoriel(BigInteger n, BigInteger m) {       //calcule le factoriel pour n'importe quel entier.  
    if (n.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) < 1) return m;             //    théoriquement valide pour tout entier dont n! < 2^2147483647, mais 
    return factoriel(n.subtract(BigInteger.ONE), n.multiply(m));//    limité par la capacité de la pile (à cause de la récursion). 
}                                                               

static BigInteger fact(int n) {                                 //convertir l'entree en BigInteger et lancer la recursion
    if(n < 0) {
        return BigInteger.valueOf(-1);
    }
    BigInteger b = BigInteger.valueOf(n);
    return factoriel(b, BigInteger.ONE);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {                        //demonstration
    String valeurRecu = "";
    int valeur;
    BigInteger resultat;
    System.out.println("Calcul Factoriel\n");
    while(!valeurRecu.contentEquals("q")){
        System.out.println("Entrer la valeur a calculer (q - quitter) : ");
        Scanner entree = new Scanner(System.in);
        valeurRecu = entree.nextLine();
        if (valeurRecu.contentEquals("q")) entree.close();
        else {
            try {
                valeur = Integer.parseInt(valeurRecu);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e){  
                System.out.println("Pas un entier. Essayer encore.\n");
                continue;
              } 
            try {
                resultat = fact(valeur);
                if(resultat.compareTo(BigInteger.valueOf(-1)) == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Valeur negative. Essayer encore.\n");
                }
                else System.out.println("Factoriel " + valeur + " -> " + fact(valeur) + "\n");
            }
        } catch(StackOverflowError e) {
            System.out.println("Depassement de la pile. Essayer encore.\n");
        }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Au revoir! :)\n");
  }
}
```

Here is some sample output :

```
Calcul Factoriel

Entrer la valeur a calculer (q - quitter) : 0
Factoriel 0 -> 1

Entrer la valeur a calculer (q - quitter) : 1
Factoriel 1 -> 1

Entrer la valeur a calculer (q - quitter) : 2
Factoriel 2 -> 2

Entrer la valeur a calculer (q - quitter) : 3
Factoriel 3 -> 6

Entrer la valeur a calculer (q - quitter) : 4
Factoriel 4 -> 24

Entrer la valeur a calculer (q - quitter) : 10
Factoriel 10 -> 3628800
    
Entrer la valeur a calculer (q - quitter) : 8000
Factoriel 8000 -> 518418106.......

Entrer la valeur a calculer (q - quitter) : 9050
Factoriel 9050 -> 480838025.......

Entrer la valeur a calculer (q - quitter) : 9100
Factoriel 9100 -> 

Entrer la valeur a calculer (q - quitter) : 31400
Factoriel 31400 -> 

Entrer la valeur a calculer (q - quitter) : 31401
Depassement de la pile. Essayer encore.
```

Comment: Can you show some values for small numbers of factorial?  I'd like to make sure that the first 10 or 20 factorials are computed correctly.

Comment: @markspace sure, I will edit to include that

Comment: @JimGarrison I've done tons of debugging. There is a system.out.println directly after the call which executes. Ive also tried using a Thread.sleep to wait for the number. I'm not sure how putting a breakpoint after the call would tell me anything at all. Wouldn't that just pause the program?? 

As I said, Im a new coder and Ive tried to validate my guesses by reading online resources and trying every tool I know in terms of debugging.

also, how am I supposed to check if the value of 10000! is valid if it is not printing to the screen? Please read my question carefully next time.

Comment: @LewisMayonnaise, most likely eclipse fails to print very long lines into console (factorial of 8000 has ~30K digits) so maybe you should use files to output your results.  [What is factorial of 8000](https://coolconversion.com/math/factorial/What-is-the-factorial-of_8000_%3F)

Comment: @AlexRudenko Awesome, that solved the issue. Looks like the values are in fact being calculated, just not printed to the screen.

Comment: Did you know you could just use a logarithmic identity called [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) to do this with much less computation?. It's pretty accurate too

Comment: @Cenfracee that is interesting! I am specifically testing tail-recursive functions though so I am bound to the problems they bring me.

Comment: Using stirling's approximation I estimate that n! < 2^2147483647 for n < 10^8 or so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The factorial method works fine but you do get relatively consistent overflow when exceeding the stack size.  The count for me is somewhere about 9000-10000 calls.  Remember that for each recursion, the large values on n! are taking up quite a bit of space in the `BigInteger` object.  So the SO is occurring somewhat early in stack trace.

What I suggest you do is print the values to a file instead of to the console of the IDE.  That way you can determine if it is the IDE (probably) or the program (probably not).  I know for Eclipse there is an internal buffer size for the console that one must set as well as a max line size.

```
static int count;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    count = 0;
    int n = 20000;
    BigInteger f = fact(n);
    
}
static BigInteger factoriel(BigInteger n, BigInteger m) {
    // calcule le factoriel pour n'importe quel entier.
    if (n.compareTo(BigInteger.ONE) < 1)
        return m; // théoriquement valide pour tout entier dont n! < 2^2147483647, mais
    
    count++;
    BigInteger f = null;
    try {
      f = factoriel(n.subtract(BigInteger.ONE), n.multiply(m));// limité par la capacité de la pile (à cause de la récursion).
    } catch(StackOverflowError e) {
        System.out.println(count);
    }
    return f;
}
    
static BigInteger fact(int n) { // convertir l'entree en BigInteger et lancer la recursion
    if (n < 0) {
        return BigInteger.valueOf(-1);
    }
    BigInteger b = BigInteger.valueOf(n);
    return factoriel(b, BigInteger.ONE);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

as simple as

```
public static BigInteger find(BigInteger B)
    {
        BigInteger res=BigInteger.ONE;
        int b=B.intValue();
        for(int i=1;i<=b;i++)
        {
            res=res.multiply(new BigInteger(new Integer(i).toString()));
            //System.out.println(res);
        }
        return res;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, but this does not answer any component of the question. 

The function I am writing is intended to test the limits of a *recursive* factorial function. Welcome to the site!

Comment: **OUTPUT:** 9050

12.0838 Sec
07:28:21
11/02/20

Comment: recursion is a overhead

Comment: It is true that recursion has more overhead, but I am specifically testing tail-recursive functions. If I was REALLY trying to optimize the code, I would not use recursion. But that is a different challenge.

Comment: the **Code** I posted can produce factorial more than **9050 !** ```System.out.println(find(9050));```

Comment: I understand. But the function MUST be recursive I said. It must be recursive. I will edit the question if that helps you. I have to use recursion. The loop is not an option.

Answer (score -2):

If you want **recursive way**

```
public static BigInteger find(BigInteger B)
    {
        BigInteger res=BigInteger.ONE;
        if(B.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO)==0)
            res=BigInteger.ONE;
        else
        {
            res=B.multiply(find(B.subtract(new BigInteger(new Integer(1).toString()))));
            //System.out.println(res);
        }
        return res;
    }
```

**29.9255 Sec
07:47:45
11/02/20**